# Camel : Adding multiple to inside loop

Tags: java, apache-camel

I am using looping in my code. I am aware that the loop breaks on the occurrence of first `to` as stated in [Apache Camel: Route loop is lost when choice is added to the path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19181813/apache-camel-route-loop-is-lost-when-choice-is-added-to-the-path)

Now, I have a route definition in which I want to have the routing across different channels before the loop ends. For example :

```
.loop(simple("${header." + FILE_COUNT + "}"))
    .to("direct:file-iterator")
.end()

from("direct:file-iterator").id("file-iterator")
                                    .to("direct:read-file-checksum")    
                                    .to("direct:file-unzip")
```

Is there any workaround for this kind of scenario as in my code only the first to gets executed after first iteration?

Comment: Could you please rephrase your problem, I don't get it.

Comment: Yeah, my problem is that in the first iteration, the routing is done as direct:file-iterator->direct:read-file-checksum->direct:file-unzip. But in the second iteration, only direct:file-iterator->direct:read-file-checksum path gets executed.

Comment: You need to update the exchange before routing the message to "direct:file-iterator".

Comment: didn't get you. What do you mean by updating the exchange? Did you mean to say I need to change the file count manually?

Comment: can u put a log statement between read-file-checksum and fire-unzip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This route:

```
public void configure() {
   from("direct:start")
       .loop(2)
       .log("CamelLoopIndex = ${header.CamelLoopIndex}")
       .to("direct:file-iterator")
       .end();

   from("direct:file-iterator")
       .id("file-iterator")
       .log("  in file-iterator")
       .to("direct:read-file-checksum")
       .to("direct:file-unzip");

    from("direct:read-file-checksum")
       .log("    in read-file-checksum");

    from("direct:file-unzip")
       .log("    in direct:file-unzip");
    }
}
```

Leads to following output:

```
[main] route1                         INFO  CamelLoopIndex = 0
[main] file-iterator                  INFO    in file-iterator
[main] route2                         INFO      in read-file-checksum
[main] route3                         INFO      in direct:file-unzip
[main] route1                         INFO  CamelLoopIndex = 1
[main] file-iterator                  INFO    in file-iterator
[main] route2                         INFO      in read-file-checksum
[main] route3                         INFO      in direct:file-unzip
```

This is what I would expect. If this route corresponds to your setup, then your problem is not a `loop` problem and you should have look into the `direct:file-unzip` route.